# What is the meaning of the word 'some' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In 2012 the police massacred 41 striking mineworkers, shooting some in the back.

Comment: It means the police killed some (maybe 10, 15 or 20) of the striking mine workers by shooting them in the back.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here. Especially [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **Try a dictionary if you want to know what a word or phrase means, how it evolved, or how it is pronounced**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

41 striking mine-workers were killed by the police, and police killed some of them (say 5 or 10) by shooting them at the back.

Comment: Using **at** before the back is not idiomatic. Contrast "Can you look me in the eye?" with "Can you look me at the eye?". Also Your answer has already been posted by another user in the comment and doesn't provide any additional information. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).